# Quickly transfer file from iOS device to new Windows computer

Tags: ios, windows

I often need to transfer files from my iOS devices to university PCs. The university PCs always delete all user-installed programs and files upon logging off. What is the easiest way to transfer a file from my iOS device to the Windows PC?

I currently upload the file to Google Drive and then download it again on the PC, but this requires me to log in and relatively takes too much time.

I tried using SnapDrop (snapdrop.net or yg.gl), which is a sort of browser-based “AirDrop” service which works across OSes. However, neither device can see each other since it only works if you’re on the same WiFi network (the PC is connected to Ethernet).

Is there any faster way of securely transferring files from my iOS device, which wouldn’t require me to install anything? (I would otherwise need to install it every time I logged in, which would make the process slow)

Comment: Doesn't your university have a file share or home directory on the network - or with windows a roaming profile

Comment: How about using something like an  [iXpand Flash Drive](https://www.sandisk.com/home/mobile-device-storage/ixpand)?

Comment: A USB thumb drive can be a [potent attack device](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/heres-a-list-of-29-different-types-of-usb-attacks/) and the university may have disabled or removed USB capability on public facing machines out of security concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I think uploading to Google Drive is the best solution without installing any programs. If you use your email in your university anyway, you can email the files to yourself and then download it again.

Comment: Actually, you don’t actually have to send the email. Just create the message (some apps require a To: address) attach the file(s), then let it sit in the Drafts for